# Переписать код Matlab на С/C++/C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, matlab

Здравствуйте. Мне нужен переписать данный код написанный в матлаб, на какой-нибудь из языков C/C++/C#. Стоит ли использовать opencv? Другой вопрос, как реализовать подобную запись при поиске блоков на другом языке. Заранее спасибо.

```
function test(fname)
     if (nargin < 1); fname = 'test.bmp'; end
%Считываем изображение и конвертируем его в массив double + делаем изображение квадратным:
IMG = double(imread(fname)) / 255; len = size(IMG); len = min(len(1 : 2)); IMG = IMG(1 : len, 1 : len, :);
%Формируем массив ранговых блоков: (NOTE: mod(len, len1) == 0)!!!
num1 = 10; len1 = floor(len / num1);
for i = 1 : num1; for j = 1 : num1; ind1(i, j).row = (i - 1) * len1 + [1 : 1 : len1]; ind1(i, j).col = (j - 1) * len1 + [1 : 1 : len1]; end; end
%Формируем массив доменных блоков:
num2 = num1 - 1; len2 = 2 * len1;
for i = 1 : num2; for j = 1 : num2; ind2(i, j).row = (i - 1) * len1 + [1 : 2 : len2]; ind2(i, j).col = (j - 1) * len1 + [1 : 2 : len2]; end; end
```

Comment: Ух, сколько минусов. Сочувствую. Вопрос-то можно было хороший сделать. Конкретно «как реализовать подобную запись при поиске блоков на другом языке» — очень подходящий вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток!

Правильно понимаю, что данный код вам нужно просто подключить к C# проекту ?
Если да, то просто из-под Matlab скомпилируйте DLL с этим кодом и используйте его. Подключаете вновь созданную DLL,  и далее вызываете из нее функцию. Вот тут [инструкция](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132487/).